# fme layered navigation Undefined variable: html

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

i have a problem with **fme layered navigation** with the following **errors** i don't how this happened  any body could help me please ?

> Notice: Undefined variable: html  in
>   /var/www/html/app/code/local/FME/Layerednav/Block/Rewrite/RewriteCatalogCategoryView.php
>   on line 18

https://znbaq.com/for-her/women-clothes/women-dress.html

[image]

Comment: provide code of that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have this extension installed in my one of the project, So replace your file code with below code

```
class FME_Layerednav_Block_Rewrite_RewriteCatalogCategoryView extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View
{ 
    public function getProductListHtml()
    {
        $html = '';   
        $html = parent::getProductListHtml();
        if ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getIsAnchor()){
            $html = Mage::helper('layerednav')->wrapProducts($html);
        }
        return $html;
    }   
}
```

Comment: @maali if this answer solved your problem then mark as accepted, so other users who has same problem take benefit from that

Answer (score 0):

Well this is just a notice. You got the two options.

1. Ignore the error and Turn off the developer mode
2. Debug the code and fix it

To fix it goto `html`  in

```
/var/www/html/app/code/local/FME/Layerednav/Block/Rewrite/RewriteCatalogCategoryView.php
```

on line 18 and there will be a variable named $html . You will have to go through the code to check the usage of this variable. you may use `isset()` to remove this notice but make sure to check that it is not affecting the existing functionality of the site.

```
if(isset($html)){
 //code here
}
```

Or simply initialize the variable `$html`